# AWStats not ignoring configured user agent blacklist

Tags: awstats

I'm trying to configure AWStats so that it ignores my benchmarks, which I usually run with `ab` (Apache Benchmark).

The following entry did not change anything, the entries are still considered:

```
SkipUserAgents="REGEX[ApacheBench.*] ApacheBench/2.3"
```

And yes, I deleted the old AWStats result (to force re-creation). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. In the end, the `SkipUserAgents` entry is correctly processed, but I had set `LogFormat=4` because it said Apache there. But `LogFormat=1` is the correct format in my case - this also solves user agent parsing and thus the problem.